# Polymer : Watch the changed Property from outside of an Component

Tags: javascript, html, polymer, web-component

I've Polymer Webcomponent.

My problem is now, outside of the Component I use knockout for DataBinding scenarios. Now I wanted to create my own Knockout Binding Type, wich is able to use twoWay-Binding with Poylmer objects. For this I need to subscribe to the Property observer from outside of the component. Is this possible? when, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to subscribe to property-change notifications when the Polymer property has `notify: true`.

> #### [Property change notification events (notify)](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/properties#notify)
>
> When a property is set to `notify: true`, an event is fired whenever the property value changes. The event name is:
>
> ```
> _property-name_-changed
> ```
>
> Where *`property-name`* is the dash-case version of the property name. For example, a change to `this.firstName` fires `first-name-changed`.
>
> These events are used by the two-way data binding system. External scripts can also listen for events (such as `first-name-changed`) directly using `addEventListener`.
>
> For more on property change notifications and the data system, see [Data flow](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-system#data-flow).

So, if you wanted to subscribe to `<x-foo>.bar` externally to interop with Knockout, you could use `addEventListener()` for the `bar-changed` event:

```
var foo = document.querySelector('x-foo');
foo.addEventListener('bar-changed', function(e) {
  console.log('new bar:', e.detail.value);
});
```

```js
HTMLImports.whenReady(() => {
  Polymer({
    is: 'x-foo',
    properties : {
      bar: {
        type: String,
        value: 'Hello world!',
        notify: true
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+1.11.3/webcomponents+webcomponents+:v0/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
</head>
<body>
  <x-foo></x-foo>
  <script>
    window.addEventListener('WebComponentsReady', function() {
      var foo = document.querySelector('x-foo');
      foo.addEventListener('bar-changed', function(e) {
        console.log('new bar:', e.detail.value);
      });
      
      foo.bar = 'hey';
      foo.bar = 'there!';
    });
  </script>

  <dom-module id="x-foo">
    <template>[[bar]]</template>
  </dom-module>
</body>
```

<sup>[codepen](http://codepen.io/tony19/pen/mAYEpj?editors=1010)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

I've now solved the following way:

```
        ko.bindingHandlers['polymer'] = {
            'init': function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings) {
                var eventsToHandle = valueAccessor() || {};
                ko.utils.objectForEach(eventsToHandle, function (eventName, value) {
                    if (typeof eventName == "string") {
                        var polymerEvent = eventName.replace(/([a-zA-Z])(?=[A-Z])/g, '$1-').toLowerCase() + '-changed';
                        var listener = function(e) {
                            value(e.detail.value);
                        };
                        element.addEventListener(polymerEvent, listener);
                        ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function () {
                            element.removeEventListener(polymerEvent, listener);
                        });
                    }
                });
            },
            'update': function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings) {
                var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor()) || {};
                ko.utils.objectForEach(value, function (attrName, attrValue) {
                    attrValue = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(attrValue);
                    element[attrName] = attrValue;
                });
            }
        };
```